# Implementing python script debugging like an IDE

Tags: python, c++, c-api

My application makes use of user creatable python scripts to interact with the application. I am using the python c API for this and therefore use the dlls. I neither use nor intend to deploy the python.exe itself to end users. To make things more difficult, I also want to call the scripts out off memory, not from a file.

How can I implement such debugging functionality? All I can find is

```
python -m pdb myscript.py
```

That means calling the exe (=other process), and saving the script to a file. Also, that unfortunately pops up another window.

There are some Py_* debugging methods in the API, but I do not know how to implement them correctly or if they are suitable for my use case at all.

Currently I think the way to go is starting a hidden debugger, attach somehow to the python system, and read/write back the communication to the application. Just that I have no starting point.

Comment: I'm not sure if KDevelop implements this, but take a look at its Python plugin: https://cgit.kde.org/kdev-python.git/tree/

Comment: You might make your question a little more explicit about what you want to do.  I’m imagining something like showing the user’s python source code in a window and single-stepping through its execution, setting breakpoints, showing the current values of various python variables, etc... is that what you have in mind?

Comment: Yes, stepping, breakpoints, etc is required. I would prefer to show the code inside a "code widget" inside my application.

Comment: Kdevelop starts an external process and uses the filesystem. Good see though.